# Mobile Site Width Issue on Android

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Okay, this is driving me nuts!  I'm working on a site for my wife (http://www.margaretberlo.com) that is supposed to automatically detect mobile browsers then redirect to m.margaretberlo.com.  So far, the redirect works, but I can't seem to get the page width to work correctly.  I'm using iWebKit as my base and not doing anything really complex, but the "tributton" section is always too large on the Android or Blackberry browser.

I've tried media queries (although that's already part of the iWebKit framwork), I've played with the  and with the initial-scale=1 stuff.  I've also noticed the background doesn't scale with the site, which I think is related, but not quite as big an issue as the tributton thing.

Is anyone familiar enough with the iWebKit framework or working with different mobile devices to point me in the right direction?  I've been searching and I'm either just missing this or haven't hit on the right solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your tributton out of the logo div.. 
Then add this css

```
#tributton a {
width: 30%;
}
```